# Ways to create a copy of an existing Database in Amazon Redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I come from a Microsoft SQL Server background and of late working on Amazon Redshift. Was looking for options to create a copy of development database for QA. The quickest way to accomplish this in SQL Server would be to generate scripts with schema & data for instance or use SSIS. What are the different options to accomplish the same in Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is taking a snapshot of your existing Redshift cluster and restoring to a new one. As Redshift is compatible with Postgres, you could also use Postgres backup tools, but it would be slower, more difficult to maintain and probably more expensive.